# RelationalModel relation field at NULL after job's done

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, backbone-relational, relational-model

I got a wtf problem that I can't figure out. I explain :

I have a model named Product :

```
var Product = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend(
{
    urlRoot: Backbone.rootApiUrl + '/products',
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        current_price: '',
        categories: '',
        duration: '',
        shipping_cost: '',
        start_date: '',
        user_id: null,
        is_buy_it_now: ''
    },

    relation: [{
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        key: 'user_id',
        relatedModel: User,
        autoFetch: true
    }]
});
```

My field `user_id` is a foreign key for one User (which is also a Model in Backbone) :

```
var User = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend(
{
    urlRoot: Backbone.rootApiUrl + '/users',
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        password: '',
        card_nb: '',
        cart_total: ''
    }
});
```

My fetch relations work perfectly in each separate model. But when i put a relation between the `Product.user_id` and my User model, a wtf error occurs.

I've tried everything possible : all the keys (`keySource`, `keyDestination` ........... with all values possibles). I've even put breakpoints into the Relation Lib to be able to watch what happened ... Nothing to say. Even StackOverflow doesn't know this bug :P (Or i badly searched)

The final problem is :

- My product is correctly sent by the API and set in Backbone (OK).
- The field `user_id` is first set at a number by the Product API response, and then put at NULL by Relational instead of being replaced by the object User (WHY ?)
- When I watch my network debugger, Relational calls the API for the User object (it's all right here) with the `user_id` number (OK). The server response is good, with the right user in JSON (OK). But Relational doesn't bind this response object with the field `user_id`, which is now .... NULL (NOT OK).

  - So I got a User object lost (but I can console.log() it if I put a success function in my autoFetch), not correctly linked to his parent Product with the field `user_id`.

**EDIT :** a JSFiddle is available here http://jsfiddle.net/gjdass/WNWrm/ (Be careful, the API can be long to respond, about 10sec, it's normal).

Thanks in advance :/ Sorry for the time you may take for this.

Comment: I think the only other question I have is what API are you using?  I am assuming you are doing some shopping cart stuff? IS this like a shopify Call or some other products API or is the API you refer to backbone.js

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for answer. No, it's a pretty simple API self-made in Python (with flask). It's for a School practice actually. The API responds well - like : _{ username:"exemple", password:"*****", mail:"exemple@exemple.com" .... }_. Nothing special is done on the server-side, pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Does it behave any differently if you remove the default value of `user_id`?  I wonder if it's fetching the relation and then applying the default value of `null`.

You might also try setting `Backbone.Relational.showWarnings` to `true` if it isn't already, and check your console for any warnings.

Comment: Hi :) The warnings was already enabled, no warning on the page. I removed user_id from my defaults array, but user_id is still NULL after the fetching is done. I really don't understand this bug ... [Here a console result image](http://goo.gl/K0iwno) and a [Second image](http://goo.gl/adTjX9) showing User are well requested and sent by the API.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when `autoFetch` is `false`?

Comment: Exactly the same yeah. It means it's not the autoFetch who sets the field at NULL after fetching the User. I'm going crazy xD

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        key: 'id',
        keyDestination: 'user_id',
        includeInJSON: 'user_id',
        autoFetch: true,
        relatedModel: User
    }]
```

I couldn't make heads or tails of the backbone-relational documentation.  Apparently `key` is supposed to reference the id of the related model, but it doesn't seem to do that in any of their examples.  I wonder if their examples actually work?  Anyway, I think this fixes your issue: setting `key` to the key from the related model and setting `keyDestination` and `includeInJSON` so it knows how to set and serialize the result into the product object.

Comment: Hi ! I tested this here : http://jsfiddle.net/gjdass/WNWrm/19/. It appears that in the global JSON of my Product Object, `user_id` is still `null`. But when i'm doing a `pruduct.get('user_id')`, it displays the id ..... I don't  understand, it's the same object !! Anyway, even the number id is false cause Relational has to put the entire object `User` in this field, not just the id. I don't understand, and like you said, there doc is not right ...

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the backbone relational documentation closely, you'll notice none of the examples they give are HasOne with a reverseRelation of HasMany.  As such, it seems that functionality is untested (except by you!) and non-functioning.  Try the relationship the other way:

```
var User = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend(
{

    urlRoot: 'http://noraj.fr:5000/users',
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        password: '',
        card_nb: '',
        cart_total: ''
    },

    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'products',
        relatedModel: 'Product',
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'id',
            keySource: 'user_id',
            keyDestination: 'user_id',
            includeInJSON: true
        }            
    }]            
});
// Product Model
var Product = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend(
{

    urlRoot: 'http://noraj.fr:5000/products',
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        current_price: '',
        categories: '',
        duration: '',
        shipping_cost: '',
        start_date: '',
        is_buy_it_now: '',
        user_id: null
    }        
});
```

Comment: Hi. There is something i don't understand here. The relation is reversed, I'm ok with that, but when I want to display a product list to my client, with this code, i have to ask users instead of products. It's not logic is it ? If i want to display a product list, I'm supposed to call `http://noraj.fr:5000/products`, not `/users`. Or I don't  understand something here (it's possible :P ).
I tested this on JSFiddle. The fact is that when i call `http://noraj.fr:5000/products` to get my products, the `/users` API is not called anymore. The `user_id` is a number, but there is no fetch done.